# Extend a gauge transformation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $P$ is a principal bundle on $M$.  Let $U^\prime\Subset U\Subset M$ be strictly contained precompact open subsets. Let $g\in C^\infty(U, \hbox{Ad}P|_U)$  be a gauge transformation of $P$ on $U$, is it always possible to extend $g|_{U^\prime}$ to be a global gauge transformation, whatever it looks like?

I guess it is true (at least in some cases, for example compact structure group) and tried to construct an extension via the adjoint bundle $\mathfrak{g} _P=\hbox{ad}P$ (since  extensions are usually dealt with vector bundles) and exponential map,  but I just could not figure it out.

Also, if in general this is not true, is it true under some conditions, for example for some particular structure groups, e.g. $U(n)$ bundles, or with some topological constraints on $M$?

This question comes when I am reading Donaldson-Kronheimer’s book *The geometry of Four-Manifolds*, Chapter 4, Lemma 4.4.6.

Comment: There could be topological obstruction caused by nontrivial topology of the fibers.

Comment: @VítTuček Could you please explain more specifically?

Comment: Vit's comment is in the spirit of the following idea: the hairy ball theorem tells you that you cannot have a continuous section of the tangent-sphere bundle over $\mathbb{S}^2$; but you can certainly have a continuous section of the bundle restricted to proper subsets. This will prevent "extensions".

Comment: @WillieWong That’s true, but I am not extending sections of a principal bundle. I want to extend a gauge transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always possible, even if the structure group is compact.

Let $M = \mathbb{R}^4, U' = \{x\mid \|x\|\in (2,3)\}, U = \{x\mid \|x\|\in (1,4)\}$, let $P = M\times SU(2)$ be the trivial $SU(2)$-bundle, and let $g: x\mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$, using the diffeomorphism $S^3\cong SU(2)$. This fulfills all of your assumptions. An extension of $G$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ would provide a retraction of $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto $S^3$, which is impossible since there is no such retraction on the third (co)homology groups.

In general, you are asking if the section $g$ of the fibration $P\times_{ad} G\to M$ extends from $U'$ to $M$. If you only ask for an extension up to homotopy, that is a section $g'$ of $\mathrm{Ad}(P)$ such that $g'|_{U'}\simeq g$, you can proceed by [obstruction theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstruction_theory): There is a sequence of obstructions with values in $H^{n+1}(M,U';\pi_n(G))$ such that the section extends up to homotopy iff all obstructions vanish. Note, however, that the extension is not unique, and that the higher obstructions are defined in terms of many previous choices and thus not very canonical.

Comment: Thank you Bertram (sorry for my late response). The question I asked was a lemma which turns out to be incorrect, however the main theorem in that section is correct. The extension of gauge transformation that I wanted could be obtained from similar arguments as in Uhlenbeck’s paper. To justify that procedure, it is easy to see that there is no obstruction since the local gauges are constructed from exponential map from a bounded subset of the Lie algebra. Nevertheless the extension can be directly constructed by an inductive argument.